# Print HTML response from nginx 405 in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, nginx

I have something like this

```
try{
    const url = 'clearlyfake';
    const response = await fetch(url);  
    //do stuff with response  
} catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

When I hit the catch in this particular instance I get an nginx 405, which is HTML. When I go the network tab and click 'response' this is what is displayed.

```
<html>
    <head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
        <hr><center>nginx/1.13.5</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to stuff this into an error bar I created. But it is not JSON, and any JSON parsing methods I try on it give me `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Is there anyway to capture and display this? Or is this an nginx config issue?

Comment: "But it is not JSON" — Well, no. It is HTML. It is very obviously HTML. Why are you trying to parse it as JSON instead of as HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML isn't JSON, so running JSON.parse() on a HTML string will give the above error.

The following should work:

```
const response = await fetch(url);
var parser = new DOMParser();
var errorDoc = parse.parseFromString(response);
```

Then you've got a DOM node with the contents of your nginx error doc. So you can either read it by calling errorDoc.getElementsByTagName('title').innerHtml to read out the name of the error code as a string or append the whole node to your document.

Comment: This worked, thanks. If anyone sees this in the future, `parseFromString` takes 2 arguments. `parseFromString(error, 'text/html');`